# Как передавать параметр типа string в SQL запрос?

Tags: python, sql, строки, postgresql

PostgreSQL:

```
sql = "select id, time from table where time ~ '22-01'"
```

Как передать параметр (тип string) вместо `'22-01'`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поставьте в {}.

Comment: да все нашел спасибо пошло поехало, не там ставил знак {}  вместо кавычек    :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из соображений безопасности (см. [SQL Injections](https://habr.com/ru/post/148151/)) и [производительности](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-prepare.html) лучше использовать параметризированные запросы:

```
qry = """
select ...
from ...
where time_update_1 ~ %s
"""
params = ["22-01"] # внимание: тип переменной `params` должен быть список или кортеж
cursor.execute(qry, params=params)
```

[Документация `psycopg3` об использовании параметров](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html)
 [(для `psycopg2`)](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Comment: Я бы дополнил ссылкой на https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html

Comment: @eri, отличная идея, спасибо! добавил)

Comment: всем пАсИбОчки :)